# How to use enable_if in a class obj?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, overloading, enable-if

The code below is OK:

```
template <class T>
std::enable_if<std::is_atomic<T>::value, bool>
foo(T t) { return true; }

template <class T>
std::enable_if<tmp::is_sequence<T>::value, bool>
foo(T t) { return false; }

int main(void){
  foo(1);  // return true
  auto std::vector<int> a{2};
  foo(a);  // return false
}
```

But when I use a class to bundle them, it can not be compiled:

```
template <class T>
class test {
public:

std::enable_if<std::is_atomic<T>::value, bool>
foo(T t) { return true; }

std::enable_if<tmp::is_sequence<T>::value, bool>
foo(T t) { return false; }
};

int main(...) {
  test<int> obj;
  obj.foo(1);
  test<std::vector<int>> obj2;
  std::vector<int> tmp{2};
  obj2.foo(tmp);
}
```

clang++ print:

```
error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
```

So I write something to cheat to the compiler(add an S in second `foo`):

```
template <class S>
std::enable_if<tmp::is_sequence<T>::value, bool>
foo(T t) { return false; }
```

It still can not work:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, bool>'
```

How can I make it work in a class?

Comment: um. what library exposes `std::Enable_if` ? Or did you mean [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry for the spell mistake

Comment: You are trying to apply SFINAE to something that is not a function template. That's not going to work. `T` is not deduced - it's set in stone the moment you specialize `test`. For a given `test<X>`, the class has two normal (non-template) member functions, both with the signature `bool foo(X)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both member-functions should have different template parameter (following will work ok)

```
template <class T>
class test {
public:

template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_atomic<U>::value, bool>::type
foo(U t) { return true; }

template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<tmp::is_sequence<U>::value, bool>::type
foo(U t) { return false; }

};
```

Comment: yes, I redefined it, u can think std::enable_if in my code is a my version. It is not the key point in this question.

Comment: At which point, `T` serves no purpose and `test` may just as well be a regular (non-template) class, or even a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add **::type** after **enable_if**: (see [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if))

```
template <class T> std::enable_if<std::is_atomic<T>::value, bool>::type
foo(T t) { return true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do what you're doing, the classic idiom is to introduce a fake SFINAE argument with a default value:

```
bool foo(T t, std::enable_if<..., void*> = nullptr) { ... }
```